# Publication year versus first-available year with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

With journals moving online, the 'year' an article is published in has become more complicated when this falls toward the end of a year. For example, https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic2021287 was made available online on 2011-12-09 but was given page numbers for 2012. Particularly if one is trying to automatically import bibliographic date, the 'date' in such cases is likely to be first-online not publication year.

For clarify, the publisher show that the article was online on 2011-11-09 but in print 2012:
[image]

What is the recommended way to store this data in a BibTeX database targetting `biblatex`?

Comment: Context: I'm updating some database entries in JabRef, and it finds the date the article was first online rather than the date I need to cite :)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. The bib-file I get from your link says 2012, how does jabref find another date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "Publication Date:December 9, 2011", which is what gets picked up by JabRef if you use the 'Import from DOI' function (I don't really trust publishers BibTeX data). But the question is wider: I could type in the date by hand, and clearly I should record both '2011-12-09' and '2012', but _how_ exactly.

Comment: I realise one might say this is a library science question, I'm just wondering about the database structure - is this something that is covered

Comment: well one could say that one is the origdate and the other the date of the reprint. But it is not quite clear which one should be which. Perhaps it would be better to have a new date field. But you still probably will have to correct it manually, if jabref doesn't make this distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully agree with your remark that you should "clearly record both 2011 and 2012". I would say that the 'official' publication is 2012, so that is the one you should use - and all other dates are more administrative details. Only if you have actually read the December 2011 version, and there are differences between that version and the final version, and these differences have an impact on your discussion, then citing the online year may be useful.

Comment: @Marijn Sure, and that's what I cite. In my own subject area the difference would never come up, but I'm trying to work out if there is a `biblatex` convention for recording this information. I think `orig...` isn't right, but I'm not sure there is anything better.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `origdate`: Originally it was intended to be used for reprints and the like (where there is a greater distance between the original publication and the new version), but the standard styles never really used it and it has fallen out of favour (now the `related` function is the way to deal with reprints). I wouldn't even know which date to treat as the real publication date for `date` here. I think I'd lean towards `2012-01-02`, but I could probably be convinced that `2011-12-09` is the actual date of publication. ....

Comment: ... I'd say the current data model doesn't have date field for the 'other publication date' and we'd have to define a new date. The question is if this concept can be generalised in a useful way for other journals (one might want to preserve journal terminology here as much as possible to avoid giving the wrong impression and if every journal uses different wording that becomes a bit of a mess). Presumably the general idea works for many journals, but the details might be different. I'd be interested to hear what (if anything) prescriptive style guides say here.